# convert youtube-dl cmd command to python script

Tags: python, youtube-dl

As I know there is two ways to convert `sound.webm` into `sound.mp3` using youtube-dl

**The first method** I tried which use `ffmpeg` to convert the sound:

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)


def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')

def download_sound(url):
    ydl_opts = {

        'format': 'bestaudio/best[height=360]',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'logger': MyLogger(),
        'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['https://youtu.be/A_WzVVndUCY])
```

file size is `8mb`.

**Second method:**

```
url = 'https://youtu.be/A_WzVVndUCY'
command = ['youtube-dl', '-x', '--audio-format', 'mp3', f'{url}']
```

file size = `4mb`.

So the second method is better for me but my question is how to convert this cmd command `youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 $url` into a python script like the first method i mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily embed **youtube-dl** as:

```
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

check [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312) for more option.